# Default foreign key in laravel for relationship pointing wrongly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel asks for **users_id instead of user_id**
I have two table Users (id, name, email..) and Country (id, **user_id**, country..).

User model

```
public function countries(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

Country model

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Controller

```
$user = $user = User::find(1);
$country = new Country();
$country->country = 'TN';
$country->users()->associate($user);
$country->save();
```

Error

```
Unknown column 'users_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `countries` (`country`, `users_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

I am confused, I do not know whether I am right or wrong. Can someone Explain me why its asking for user**s**_id.

Comment: do you want each country have only one user? or every user to have one country? and is this relation really a one-to-one?

Comment: Each country have many users and each user have one country ( I was using this relation for Activation token for users)

Comment: that's what I thought. so see my answer as your current relations won't do what you want. it's a very different case.

Comment: Am I correct with the relation in the case of Activation token for new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the relationship name to `user()`:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Its working, I can figure it out, Why should I have the Model name as user and not users or Some thing else. I am new to laravel and I didn't see the document to mention specifically to use user.

Comment: Kindly explain me how to name the function, If not a link to document.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's a concept issue. if it's a normal case and you're trying to add users each has a country and you want to have the inverse relation so that you can list all users in a country.

if so, you've to add a foreign key `country_id` in the `users` table NOT a `users_id` in the countries table and so the relations should be defined like:

```
public function country(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

and in Country model

```
public function users(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

a basic role to think about a relation is:

Country-hasMany-Users

User-hasOne-Country

so the relation should be `one-to-many` and thus there must be a foreign key for the one (country in our case) in the table of the many (users table here).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, it seems like a bug to me.

I have a table 'company' with a 'user_id' field.

These two member functions return different results:

```
public function owner()               { return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); } 
public function user()                { return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); }
```

In order for it to work properly, I need to specify the second parameter. This is extremely counterintuitive to me.

```
public function owner()               { return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id'); }
public function user()                { return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); }
```

Apparently, this is intended behavior, as the 'belongsTo' method **uses the name of the parent function to determine the key**. This seems crazy to me, I would expect the Model name to determine the key.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18804